# Unknown Property in a return type

Tags: jpa, java-8, playframework-2.4, mapstruct

I am trying to use mapstruct in my Play 2.4 Java8 JPA project. Steps I have done:

Added Dependency

```
  "org.mapstruct" % "mapstruct-jdk8" % "1.1.0.Beta1",
  "org.mapstruct" % "mapstruct-processor" % "1.1.0.Beta1"
```

Model

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;            
    private String fullName;          
    private String email;
}
```

EmployeeDto

```
public class EmployeeDto {

    private String full_name;
    private String email;
}
```

EmployeeMapper

```
@Mapper
public interface EmployeeMapper {

    EmployeeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(EmployeeMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "fullName", target = "full_name")
    EmployeeDto employeeToEmployeeDto(Employee employee);
}
```

But its giving me a compilation error

```
 error: Unknown property "full_name" in return type.
[error]     @Mapping(source = "fullName", target = "full_name")
```

What could be the issue for the error?

Comment: Do you have a setter for that property in the DTO type?

Comment: @Gunnar I dont have setters for DTO

Comment: That's the problem then; MapStruct doesn't use reflection to get or set state in the mapped types, plain getter/setter calls are used in the generated code to propagate state from source to target. There is an issue to support accessible fields (e.g. public fields), but that wouldn't help you either as you got them declared as private.

Comment: @Gunnar thanks that worked for me.

Comment: Ok; Added this as an answer then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bean on the target side needs to have setters for the mapped properties.

MapStruct doesn't use reflection to get or set state in the mapped types, plain getter/setter calls are used in the generated code to propagate state from source to target.

Comment: just a small addition, if you use (or plan to use) `Lombok`, then this error can be fixed by adding a dependency of `Lombok` to the `annotation processor`in pom.xml.  Example: `<path><groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
</path>`

Answer (score 19):

**Additional case for other developers:** If you use Lombok, maven uses only the MapStruct processor. So Lombok cannot generate the getters/setters. To resolve that, add the lombok dependency in the `annotationProcessorPaths`.

Also if you use Lombok 1.8.16 and above, you have to add `lombok-mapstruct-binding` too.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${projectlombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.8.16 and above -->
            <path>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This example helped me to put your answer in the right context and location: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-lombok/pom.xml Thanks for the hint about the lombok-mapstruct-binding :-)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help Pim :)

Comment: Not sure why this isn't included in the official documentation. You saved me, thank you for taking the time to post this reply.

Comment: Putting `lombok` first, and `mapstruct-processor` second in the list of `annotationProcessorPaths` made it work for me even without `lombok-mapstruct-binding`.

I tried it with lombok version 1.18.22 and mapstruct-processor version 1.4.2.Final.

Answer (score 8):

Hello brothers and sisters.

In my case, to work with Mapstruct(0.2.0) and Lombok(1.18.16) at the same time, the below  block should come first or in the middle of the three 'path' blocks.
I mean either 1)mapstruct, 2) lombok-mapstruct-binding and 3) lombok or 1) lombok-mapstruct-binding, 2)mapstruct and 3) lombok worked for me.

```
<path>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
   <version>0.2.0</version>
</path>
```

Comment: Using version 0.2.0 instead of 0.1.0 saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Relevant bit of info from https://mapstruct.org/faq/

> Can I use MapStruct together with Project Lombok?
>
> Yes, as of MapStruct 1.2.0.Beta1 and Lombok 1.16.14.
>
> Project Lombok is an annotation processor that (amongst other things) adds getters and setters to the AST (abstract syntax tree) of compiled bean classes. AST modifications are not foreseen by Java annotation processing API, so quite some trickery was required within Lombok as well MapStruct to make both of them work together. Essentially, MapStruct will wait until Lombok has done all its amendments before generating mapper classes for Lombok-enhanced beans.
>
> An example for using the two projects together can be found here.
>
> If you are using Lombok 1.18.16 or newer you also need to add lombok-mapstruct-binding in order to make Lombok and MapStruct work together.
>
> If you are on an older version of MapStruct or Lombok, the solution is to put the JavaBeans to be amended by Lombok and the mapper interfaces to be processed by MapStruct into two separate modules of your project. Then Lombok will run in the compilation of the first module, causing the bean classes to be complete when MapStruct runs during the compilation of the second module.